How to set the "Set operation" in a Sirius Properties View?
I created a model and a viewpoint in table format that shows me the data based on the rules I set.
I have created a new properties view that when i select a row of the table shows some information of the selected element. My problem is that one of these properties contained in a textbox should allow me to change the value and reflect the changes also in the table. I added a Set operation but I can't set it correctly.

Model: The Model
PropertiesView: The Properties View

The service:getVal() method in the second image is:
public String getVal(EObject context) {
    String toReturn = "";
    if (context instanceof PropertyEntry entry) {
        IValueData data = (ValueData) entry.getValue();

        toReturn = data.getData();
    }

    return toReturn;
}

What should I put in the following fields?

Fields

I tried with these settings but they were unsuccessful:

Settings

The service:setVal(var:newValue) is:
public void setVal(EObject context, String newValue) {
    if (context instanceof PropertyEntry entry) {
         IValueData valueData = (ValueData) entry.getValue();
         valueData.setData(newValue);
    }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The documentation for the 'Set' operation gives a bit of information:

feature name: the name of the feature to set, e.g. data
value expression: the value assigned to the feature, e.g. var:newValue


Thanks for the answer. I read the documentation and i already tried the way you suggest but it doesen't work. I don't understand what i miss.

Your context is probably incorrect then. Before the 'Set' operation, set up a 'Change Context' that calls some Java service of your own where you can Sysout/Debug to check the value of the 'self' variable.
